# Canon SDK - how to check if video is recording?

Tags: c#, camera, canon-sdk

This question refers to using the Canon SDK with a video capable DSLR camera.  Anyone know if there is way to check if a video is being recorded on the camera ?

I know there is no way to start recording video with the SDK, but maybe there is way to check if one is being recorded right now ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

as the latest canon sdk contais folowing pahagraph:
6.4.3 Begin/End movie shooting

### You can begin/end movie shooting with the following operations.

```
EdsUInt32 record_start = 4; // Begin movie shooting 
err = EdsSetPropertyData(cameraRef, kEdsPropID_Record, 0, sizeof(record_start), &record_start); 
EdsUInt32 record_stop = 0; // End movie shooting 
err = EdsSetPropertyData(cameraRef, kEdsPropID_Record, 0, sizeof(record_stop), &record_stop);
```

you may check the property data and if it is set to 4 - than the video is recording.